# fastest way to python dict to json binary string

Tags: python, json, ujson

I need to convert this python dict into binary json

```
   d = {'1': 'myval', '2': 'myval2'}

   json_binary_str = b'{"1": "myval", "2": "myval2"}'
```

in python 3, I have this :

```
   import ujson
   ujson.dumps(d)
```

but, this does not create binary string.
How can I do this ?

Comment: A JSON string is text. If you want to encode it then that's your business.

Comment: How about this? bytes(json.dumps(d), encoding='utf-8')

Comment: `json.dumps(d).encode()`

Answer (score 4):

In the RFC https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159, it says:

```
JSON text SHALL be encoded in UTF-8, UTF-16, or UTF-32
```

At first glance it does seem that Python isn't really following the spec when you first look at this after all what does it mean to encode something when it remains a Python3 'str' string, however Python is doing some encoding for you nonetheless.  Try this:

```
>>> json.dumps({"Japan":"日本"})
'{"Japan": "\\u65e5\\u672c"}'
```

You can see that the Japanese has got converted to unicode escapes, and the resultant string is actually ASCII, even if it's still a Python str.  I'm unsure how to get json.dumps() to actually give you utf-8 sequences - for interoperability purposes - if you wanted them, however for all practical purposes this is good enough for most people.  The characters are there and will be interpreted correctly.  It's easy to get binary with:

```
>>> json.dumps({"Japan":"日本"}).encode("ascii")
b'{"Japan": "\\u65e5\\u672c"}'
```

And python does the right thing when loading back in:

```
>>> json.loads(json.dumps({"Japan":"日本"}).encode("ascii"))
{'Japan': '日本'}
```

But if you don't bother encoding at all, the loads() still figures out what to do as well when given a str:

```
>>> json.loads(json.dumps({"Japan":"日本"}))
{'Japan': '日本'}
```

Python is - as ever - trying to be as helpful as possible in figuring out what you want and doing it, but this is perplexing to people who dig a little deeper, and in spite of loving Python to bits I sympathise with the OP.  Whether this kind of 'helpful' behaviour is worth the confusion is a debate that will rage on.

Worth noting that if the next thing to be done with the output is writing to a file, then you can just do:

```
pathlib.Path("myfile.json").open("w").write(json_data)
```

Then you don't need it binary because the file is opened in text mode and encoding is done for you.

Comment: *"I'm unsure how to get json.dumps() to actually give you utf-8 sequences"* - that'd be `ensure_ascii=False`

Answer (score 0):

If you need to convert the JSON to binary, you need to convert it to a string using `dumps()`, then you can convert it to binary as shown below

```
  import json

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sent_data = {'1': 'myval', '2': 'myval2'}
    dumped_json_string = json.dumps(sent_data)
    binary_data = ' '.join(format(ord(letter), 'b') for letter in dumped_json_string)
    print binary_data

    jsn = ''.join(chr(int(x, 2)) for x in binary_data.split())
    received_data = json.loads(jsn)
    print received_data
```

the output of binary_data is

```
1111011 100010 110001 100010 111010 100000 100010 1101101 1111001 1110110 1100001 1101100 100010 101100 100000 100010 110010 100010 111010 100000 100010 1101101 1111001 1110110 1100001 1101100 110010 100010 1111101
```

the output of received_data is

```
{u'1': u'myval', u'2': u'myval2'}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Code is not working in python 3.
what about bytes(   ) ?

Comment: what about usage of bytes(   ) ?

Comment: I did not get your point, what do you want to do? can you explain

Comment: we can use  bytes(mystring,  'utf-8')

Answer (score 0):

I see this as a 2-step problem

**Step 1:** Convert json to string
`my_string = json.dumps(my_json)`

**Step 2:** Convert string to binary string
`my_binary_string = my_string.encode('utf-8')`

Or obviously in one line
`my_binary_string = json.dumps(my_json).encode('utf-8')`